# i'm finding problems with button click in android studio, but i keep getting the 'getSettings' error and (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView); error

Tags: java, android, webview

[image]

[image]

I'm finding problems solving the above WebView errors.

Comment: Don't post screenshots of code, post the actual code in the question.

Answer (score 4):

```
public class WebView extends AppCompactActivity
```

To

```
public class MyWebView extends AppCompactActivity
```

WebView is an android class name you do not use this name.

Comment: it still creates an error in the manifest.xml. '<activity android:name=".WebView" />'

Comment: You must change this name to `<activity android:name=".MyWebView" /> ` activity name